# with close-up insert -- no indefinite article in front of "close-up insert"?

Tags: grammar

Example with a context ([Did A UFO 'Not Made By Man' Hover Over Chile?](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/05/13/chile-ufo-not-made-by-man_n_7155738.html)):

> The story unfolds in April 2013 when two photos emerge of an unusual disc-shaped object (seen below with **close-up insert**) over the Collahuasi copper mine in northern Chile. Several eyewitnesses watched as the UFO remained in the sky for over an hour, moving around and hovering.

Isn't there supposed to be an indefinite article in front of *close-up insert*? Did the author make a mistake or is this absolutely normal? What do you think?

Comment: I'd call it a reporterese ellipsis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... (seen below with close-up insert)

This section is in brackets. The reason is, this is not part of the story. It is like an instruction explaining where to find the picture, and what the picture is about. The style of language inside the brackets is different from the style of language outside.

When we are giving written instructions, or writing titles for pictures, for example, we sometimes leave out some grammar words. For example, we might leave out the verb be. Or we might leave out article like *a*, or *the*. The language inside the brackets is using this style.

Comment: @Cookie monster: If you're learning American English, the things Auraucaria calls "brackets" are _parentheses  (. . . )_. In America, _brackets_ refers either to _square brackets [. . . ], _angle brackets <. . . >_, or _curly brackets {. . .}_, the latter sometimes called _(curly) braces_.